# Extra rows in a XLSX export via SQL Pull

Tags: powershell

Sorry if I am asking anything that is very basic but I just started PowerShell last night and I'm getting a feel for the new language.

I'm using an export to XLSX script provided by the link below:

https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/office/Export-XLSX-PowerShell-f2f0c035

I'm also using a simple SQL server pull (SQL_Connection_Script.ps1):

```
$dataSource = "####"
$user = "####"
$pwd = "####"
$database = "####"
$connectionString = "Server=$dataSource;uid=$user; pwd=$pwd;Database=$database;Integrated Security=False;"

$query = "Select * from name where id = '1000'"

$connection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
$connection.ConnectionString = $connectionString
$connection.Open()
$command = $connection.CreateCommand()
$command.CommandText  = $query

$result = $command.ExecuteReader()

$table = new-object “System.Data.DataTable”
$table.Load($result)

$table 

$connection.Close()
```

My issue is when I export this object I get the extra columns: RowError, RowState, Table, ItemArray and HasErrors.

Is there anyway to remove these columns by either a command that I am just unaware of or should I insert a dynamic Select statement, example below?

I am hoping to not have to use a dynamic Select statement if possible.

```
.\Desktop\SQL_Connection_Script.ps1 | Select $DynamicHeadersHere | Export-XLSX -path .\Desktop\testing123.xlsx -Append
```

---

So it looks like my SQL Server Pull function is the thing that is pulling in the extra fields. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

After looking around for a while I found I can exclude properties.

```
.\Desktop\SQL_Connection_Script.ps1 | Select * -ExcludeProperty RowError, RowState, HasErrors, Table, ItemArray  | Export-XLSX -path .\Desktop\testing123.xlsx -Append
```